# Angularjs: validación regex se sobre-escribe por Minlength

Tags: angularjs

Tengo un problema:
No logro que funcione dentro del mismo campo mi 
directiva con validación de RegEX, y la directiva minlength.

Ambos funcionan apropiadamente excepto que el numero de caracteres definidos en el minlength no son validados en el RegEX.

Mi directiva con RegEX:

```
angular
.module('app')
.directive('restrict', restrict);

restrict.$inject = ['$parse'];

function restrict($parse) {
var inputTypes = {
    textNumber: '[^A-Za-z0-9 _-ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]',
    text: '[^A-Za-z ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]',
    number: '[^0-9]',
    email: '[^A-Za-z.@]',
    basicTextNumber: '[^A-Za-z0-9_-]'
};

var link = function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    var exp = inputTypes[$attrs.restrict] || $attrs.restrict;
    $scope.$watch($attrs.ngModel, function(value) {
        if (!value) {
            return;
        }
        if (typeof value === 'number') { // eslint-disable-line
            value = String(value);
        }
        $parse($attrs.ngModel).assign($scope, value.replace(new RegExp(exp, 'g'), ''));
    });
};

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: link
};
```

Fragmento de mis inputs:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <input class="validate" type="text" name="nombre" ng-model="vm.users.nombre" ng-minlength="2" restrict="text" maxlength=40 data-length=40 required autocomplete="off">
                    <label ng-class="active" for="nombre">Nombre</label>

                    <div role="alert" style="color:maroon" ng-show="!registro.nombre.$pristine">
                        <span class="error" ng-show="registro.nombre.$error.required">
                            Requerido</span>
                        <span class="error" ng-show="registro.nombre.$error.minlength">
                            Minimo 2 caracteres</span>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

¿Cual puede ser el problema?

Answer (score 0):

La verdad desconocosco el problema con la directiva propia de minlength.

Pero logre solucionar el problema haciendo mi propia directiva:

De esta manera aseguro que el Regex corra antes que la verificación de tamaño mínimo y máximo. Espero y esta solución sea optima y logre salverle unas horas de investigación a cualquier novato como yo.

```
 'use strict';

 angular
 .module('app')
 .directive('valminimo', valminimo);

function valminimo() {

 function link($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl) {
     var minlength = parseInt($attrs.valminimo);

     $scope.$watch($attrs.ngModel, function(value) {
         if (!value) {
             return;
         }
         if (typeof value === 'number') {
             value = String(value);
         }

         var valid = value.length >= minlength;
         $ctrl.$setValidity('valminimo', valid);
     });
 };


 return {
     restrict: 'A',
     priority: 0,
     require: '?ngModel',
     link: link
 };
}
```